# Clearing thread safe collections while in Parallel.ForEach loop after insert to SQL database

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, thread-safety, .net-4.5, parallel.foreach

I have a long running process that uses a `Parallel.ForEach` loop. While in that loop, I'm creating instance of two different classes based on what is passed, performing minor tasks, then adding to thread safe collections.  When complete, all data needs to be inserted to SQL database.

The problem I have is the amount of work done is too large to keep in the collections until all processing is done.  I have to push what is retained to SQL occasionally then remove what was pushed from the collection so more processing can continue without running out of memory and I don't know the best way to do that.  I can easily do it if it wasn't multi-threaded by checking the count of the collections and if it is over a certain amount, call a function that would push the contents to SQL through a bulk insert or valued table then clear that collection on the next statement.   What is the best way to accomplish this within a `Parallel.ForEach`?

I'm open to using any collection that is thread safe.  So far I'm been using the `ConcurrentQueue` and thought about switching to `BlockingCollection` because I didn't see a way to clear the `ConcurrentQueue`. I don't care what order the contents are inserted, but I do need to be able to at least remove what is pushed to SQL database.

My best solution is to use `BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()`.  This way, once over x amount, I can copy the contents of that collection to another thread safe collection, perform my insert, then use that list to remove from the original using `BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()`.  Once that's done, dispose of the temp list.  I just thought there was a better way because if I have to iterate one at a time to remove, it kind of defeats the purpose of have it multi threaded.

I have seen the use of [pulse and wait](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/wait-and-pulse-method-in-threading-C-Sharp/) used but I couldn't find a good use case that seems safe.  I could have something come through after I tested the collection to be over a certain amount and get cleared before it was inserted to SQL database.

I'm using the 4.5 Framework and I'm managing two different collections that need to be pushed but not necessarily at the same time.

Comment: Take a look at [TPL Dataflow](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=microsoft+tpl+dataflow). It contains all the building blocks you'll need to coordinate the producer/consumer flows in your program and seems to me like a very good fit for the problems you are describing. Take a small detour to see what it offers. You won't regret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend clearing a concurrent collection. Instead, I would 'replace' it with a new one - and process the content from the old one while the other threads push their content to the new one.

[Interlocked.Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337971(v=vs.110).aspx) is the technique I would use to accomplish this.

Comment: ​The `Interlocked.Exchange` technique has a race condition: 1. The `Parallel.ForEach` worker A gets a reference to the collection. 2. The `Parallel.ForEach` worker B swaps the existing collection with an empty collection, and launches a background "SQL Insert" operation for the records in the old collection. 3. The `Parallel.ForEach` worker A adds an item X in the collection it had grabbed earlier (the old collection). 4. The X item is lost. It is not inserted in the database.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I didn't cover the full implementation - I was dealing with the specific narrow part of the problem they were asking about. Is your concern a theoretical risk? Yes, of course. But it is hard to be sure without the OP actually sharing code. The obvious naive approach is to "`Exchange` in a new collection and queue the old one to be written to SQL Server in 60 seconds" which solves all practical race conditions.

Comment: Sure, waiting for 60 seconds before enumerating the old collection would make race conditions astronomically unlikely. Nevertheless I wouldn't call such a system a "marvel of engineering", and I wouldn't be proud for being its author. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Fair enough. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing or swapping the concurrent collection is risky. You are opening the window for all kinds of race conditions. What you have to do is to **consume** the concurrent collection. In case of a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, the consuming method is the [`TryDequeue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1.trydequeue). Since you have a memory problem, I will suggest to use instead a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1), which is equipped with bounding capabilities. Here is an example:

```
var results = new BlockingCollection<Result>(100);

var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task producer = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount,
            CancellationToken = cts.Token
        };

        Parallel.ForEach(source, parallelOptions, item =>
        {
            Result result = GetResult(item);
            results.Add(result, cts.Token);
        });
    }
    catch { cts.Cancel(); throw; }
    finally { results.CompleteAdding(); }
});

Task consumer = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        foreach (IList<Result> batch in results
            .GetConsumingEnumerable().Buffer(100))
        {
            InsertToSqlDatabase(batch);
        }
    }
    catch { cts.Cancel(); throw; }
});

Task.WaitAll(producer, consumer);
```

This is just one of the many different ways that you can implement the desirable functionality. The `BlockingCollection<Result>` is initialized with a capacity of 100, meaning that the [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.add) method will block when you try to add the 101st item in the collection. In this example there are two separate `Task`s, the `producer` and the `consumer`. Both are running on the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool). The producer adds results in the `BlockingCollection<Result>` in parallel, and the consumer consumes the results in chunks of 100, and inserts them in the database sequentially. The batching is performed with the [`Buffer`](https://fuqua.io/Rx.NET/ix-docs/html/M_System_Linq_EnumerableEx_Buffer__1.htm) LINQ operator, from the [System.Interactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive/) package¹. In case either task fails, the other task is notified with the help of a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource), so that the whole system doesn't get stuck.

¹ <sub>The .NET 6 introduced the [`Chunk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk) LINQ operator with the same functionality.</sub>