# Parallel.ForEach: Best way to save off a collection when its record count gets high?

Tags: c#, locking, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

So I'm running a `Parallel.ForEach` that basically generates a bunch of data which is ultimately going to be saved to a database. However, since collection of data can get quite large I need to be able to occasionally save/clear the collection so as to not run into an `OutOfMemoryException`.

I'm new to using `Parallel.ForEach`, concurrent collections, and locks, so I'm a little fuzzy on what exactly needs to be done to make sure everything works correctly (i.e. we don't get any records added to the collection between the Save and Clear operations).

Currently I'm saying, if the record count is above a certain threshold, save the data in the current collection, within a `lock` block.

```
ConcurrentStack<OutRecord> OutRecs = new ConcurrentStack<OutRecord>();
object StackLock = new object();

Parallel.ForEach(inputrecords, input =>
{
  lock(StackLock)
  {  
    if (OutRecs.Count >= 50000)
    {
       Save(OutRecs);
       OutRecs.Clear();
     }
   }

  OutRecs.Push(CreateOutputRecord(input);
});

if (OutRecs.Count > 0) Save(OutRecs);
```

I'm not 100% certain whether or not this works the way I think it does. Does the lock stop other instances of the loop from writing to output collection? If not is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What about letting each thread save its own data?

Comment: In scenarios with high volume of transactions, save one by one record can be very slow, specially when databases are involved

Comment: Yeah, I definitely don't want to save every iteration. 

If there's some way for each instance of the thread to have its own collection which it could save once it hits a certain count, then save off the leftovers once it finishes - maybe that could work.

Not sure if there's a way to do that or not, literally just discovered Parallel.ForEach so I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Related: [Clearing thread safe collections while in Parallel.ForEach loop after insert to SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348945/clearing-thread-safe-collections-while-in-parallel-foreach-loop-after-insert-to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lock will work correctly but it will not be very efficient because *all* your worker threads will be forced to pause for the entire duration of each save operation. Also, locks tends to be (relatively) expensive, so performing a lock in each iteration of each thread is a bit wasteful.

One of your comments mentioned giving each worker thread its own data storage: yes, you can do this. Here's an example that you could tailor to your needs:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    // collection of objects to iterate over
    inputrecords,

    // delegate to initialize thread-local data
    () => new List<OutRecord>(),

    // body of loop
    (inputrecord, loopstate, localstorage) =>
    {
        localstorage.Add(CreateOutputRecord(inputrecord));
        if (localstorage.Count > 1000)
        {
            // Save() must be thread-safe, or you'll need to wrap it in a lock
            Save(localstorage);
            localstorage.Clear();
        }
        return localstorage;
    },

    // finally block gets executed after each thread exits
    localstorage =>
    {
        if (localstorage.Count > 0)
        {
            // Save() must be thread-safe, or you'll need to wrap it in a lock
            Save(localstorage);
            localstorage.Clear();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to define an abstraction that represents the destination for your data. It could be something like this:

```
public interface IRecordWriter<T> // perhaps come up with a better name.
{
    void WriteRecord(T record);
    void Flush();
}
```

Your class that processes the records in parallel doesn't need to worry about how those records are handled or what happens when there's too many of them. The implementation of `IRecordWriter` handles all those details, making your other class easier to test.

An implementation of `IRecordWriter` could look something like this:

```
public abstract class BufferedRecordWriter<T> : IRecordWriter<T>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<T> _buffer = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();
    private readonly int _maxCapacity;
    private bool _flushing;

    public ConcurrentQueueRecordOutput(int maxCapacity = 100)
    {
        _maxCapacity = maxCapacity;
    }

    public void WriteRecord(T record)
    {
        _buffer.Enqueue(record);
        if (_buffer.Count >= _maxCapacity && !_flushing)
            Flush();
    }

    public void Flush()
    {
        _flushing = true;
        try
        {
            var recordsToWrite = new List<T>();
            while (_buffer.TryDequeue(out T dequeued))
            {
                recordsToWrite.Add(dequeued);
            }
            if(recordsToWrite.Any())
                WriteRecords(recordsToWrite);
        }
        finally
        {
            _flushing = false;
        }
    }

    protected abstract void WriteRecords(IEnumerable<T> records);
}
```

When the buffer reaches the maximum size, all the records in it are sent to `WriteRecords`. Because `_buffer` is a `ConcurrentQueue` it can keep reading records even as they are added.

That `Flush` method could be anything specific to how you write your records. Instead of this being an abstract class the actual output to a database or file could be yet another dependency that gets injected into this one. You can make decisions like that, refactor, and change your mind because the very first class isn't affected by those changes. All it knows about is the `IRecordWriter` interface which doesn't change.

You might notice that I haven't made absolutely certain that `Flush` won't execute concurrently on different threads. I could put more locking around this, but it really doesn't matter. This will avoid most concurrent executions, but it's okay if concurrent executions both read from the `ConcurrentQueue`.

This is just a rough outline, but it shows how all of the steps become simpler and easier to test if we separate them. One class converts inputs to outputs. Another class buffers the outputs and writes them. That second class can even be split into two - one as a buffer, and another as the "final" writer that sends them to a database or file or some other destination.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the lock stop other instances of the loop from writing to output collection?

No, it doesn't. Other threads can still write to the `OutRecs` collection, because the `OutRecs.Push` operation is not protected with the same locker object (`StackLock`). Which makes your program incorrect: some `OutRecord` objects might not be saved in the database. It's a classic [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), with non-deterministic behavior.

> If not is there a better way to do this?

Yes, you could use a non-thread-safe collection, for example a `List<T>`, and synchronize each and every interaction with the collection inside the `Parallel.ForEach` loop. After the completion of the parallel loop, synchronization is not required (explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871878/are-you-there-asynchronously-written-value/28872058#28872058)). Example:

```
List<OutRecord> results = new();

ParallelOptions options = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};

Parallel.ForEach(inputRecords, options, input =>
{
    OutRecord result = CreateOutputRecord(input);
    lock(results)
    {
        results.Add(result);
        if (results.Count >= 50000)
        {
            Save(results);
            results.Clear();
        }
    }
});

if (results.Count > 0) Save(results);
```

This way all parallel activity will stop while saving the 50,000 `OutRecord`s, because all other worker threads will get blocked on the `lock` statement. In case you prefer to continue working during the `Save`, you will need to implement the producer-consumer pattern. You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348945/clearing-thread-safe-collections-while-in-parallel-foreach-loop-after-insert-to/77120547#77120547).